# Nexus 7 - 2013 - missed 5.0 rollout?

Tags: updates, nexus-7

My nexus 7 was showing "update available" but after thinking "You know if it's crap I don't want to deal with it now" (and reading later that there were some problems) I left it, 2 weeks later (a week ago) it came back, and I ignored it.

Now I want to start using Material Design, but the update has gone, have I missed my window? I doubt it but Google's update policy...

Anyway, can I "force" an update?

Comment: Try rebooting and possibly wait for it re-update.

Comment: If you __reeeaaally__ don't want to wait, you could always flash the [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) yourself. It only requires the `fastboot` tool (which is part of the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) or as a [minimal package](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790)) on a computer and a USB connection. Detailed instructions are on the images site.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Ignored 5.0 OTA update on nexus 4 now can't get it back](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93825/ignored-5-0-ota-update-on-nexus-4-now-cant-get-it-back#comment117578_93825)

Answer (score 1):

You can direct download the latest factory image [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) for your device. As far as I know, you need to note several things before force push the update:

- Power off your device.
- Enter to recovery mode (Power + Volume up and down buttons simultaneously for a few seconds).
- Locate the zipped file and extract it to update the version. (May take a while)
- Reboot

A bit of warning: Doing this will erase your all of your data and apps. Be sure to backup your data before doing this.

I hope this helps you.